# Java Script convert array of maps to map

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dictionary

I would like to make an Object made of name->value pairs of DOM elements:

```
var values = $("#kitElements input.kitElement");
  var kitElements = $.map(values, function (element) {
          return {
            [element.name]: parseInt(element.value)

          };
        });
```

This code makes an Array of Objects containing name->value pairs, but I would prefer them to be combined into one Object.

Comment: array of maps? I think it would return an array of objects - and there's plenty of questions on stack overflow on how to "convert" an array of objects to an object

Comment: Slightly confused as to what you actually want... The map function returns an array however if you want to reduce an array to a single value (for example sum all values in an array) you can use array.reduce()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer:

Unfortunately `map` is not typically the route you want to go with something like this. It doesn't allow you to combine each item together easily, it just allows you to alter the value of each item *within* the array. We want to merge this down into one object, and this procedure is called `reducing`.

JQuery does not currently have a `reduce` method attached to its Constructor. This means that, in order to perform `reduce`, you need to use straight JavaScript.

It's not too difficult, we simply use JQuery's `toArray` method to get the elements into a standard `Array` object, and then apply `reduce`.

```
values.toArray().reduce(ƒ, accumulator);
```

A `reduce` function takes an `accumulator` which is its second parameter. It's an object that can be adjusted and returned from the `reduce` function. Since we want to return an object containing all `name` and `value` pairs, we will provide an Object literal as the `accumulator`.

```
values.toArray().reduce(ƒ, {});
```

Then we simply need to write our `reduce` function (ƒ). All it does is assign the `name` as a key in the `accumulator` and the value of the input as the `value`. Lastly it will `return` the `accumulator` to be used with the next element in the array, and finally **returned** to our variable when it's finished processing through the entire thing.

*code:*

```
var values = $("#kitElements input.kitElement");
var kitElements = values.toArray().reduce(function(accumulator, element) {
  accumulator[element.name] = parseInt(element.value)
  return accumulator;
}, {});

console.log(kitElements);
```

### Example:

```js
var values = $("#kitElements input.kitElement");
var kitElements = values.toArray().reduce(function(accumulator, element) {
  accumulator[element.name] = parseInt(element.value)
  return accumulator;
}, {});

console.log(kitElements);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="kitElements">
  <input name="a" class="input kitElement" type="number" value="100" />
  <input name="b" class="input kitElement" type="number" value="200" />
  <input name="c" class="input kitElement" type="number" value="300" />
</div>
```

---

### Alternative: Using JQuery's `map` method instead of Array.prototype.`reduce`

If you're really *into* using JQuery's `map` method, you can combine it with an actual `Map` Object.

```
var kitElements = new Map($.map(values,(e) => [[e.name, +e.value]]));
```

---

### Example:

```js
var values = $("#kitElements input.kitElement");
var kitElements = new Map($.map(values,(e) => [[e.name, +e.value]]));

console.log(...kitElements.entries())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="kitElements">
  <input name="a" class="input kitElement" type="number" value="100" />
  <input name="b" class="input kitElement" type="number" value="200" />
  <input name="c" class="input kitElement" type="number" value="300" />
</div>
```

The difference when using a `Map` object is that you must use `kitElements.get(*name*)` to retrieve your element value.

You can read more about the `Map` prototype on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)